# Contact ContentResolver nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

In this class i'm attempting to go through all my contacts and put only their Name, Phone, and Email into a StringBuffer (this class is mostly copied code). The Activity worked as expected when run as a separate program and output the information via a TextView, but when I commented some things out so I could just call it as a class inside my larger program I received the following error:

```
05-25 15:29:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2137): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-735330718493-2]
05-25 15:29:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2137): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 15:29:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:91)
05-25 15:29:57.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):     at com.remoteware.gcm.Contact.fetchContacts(Contact.java:52)
```

Around Line 52 of the code:

```
Uri EmailCONTENT_URI =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;


StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();    //Line 52

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);  

// Loop for every contact in the phone
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
```

And here is the full code. I commented out the lines from the original activity(that worked) to remove the unnecessary interface.

```
package com.remoteware.gcm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;


public class Contact extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        fetchContacts();
    }


public void fetchContacts() {

        String phoneNumber = null;
        String email = null;

        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
        String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
        String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

        Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
        String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

        Uri EmailCONTENT_URI =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
        String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
        String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;


        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();    //Line 52

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);  

        // Loop for every contact in the phone
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID ));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME ));

                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER )));

                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                    output.append("\n First Name:" + name);

                    // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                        output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);


                    }

                    phoneCursor.close();

                    // Query and loop for every email of the contact
                    Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI,    null, EmailCONTACT_ID+ " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                    while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {

                        email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA));

                        output.append("\nEmail:" + email);


                    }

                    emailCursor.close();
                }

                output.append("\n");
            }

        //  outputText.setText(output);
        }
    }
}
```

The class is then called via

```
Contact mContact = new Contact();
mContact.fetchContacts();
```

from another class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Contact is an Activity : so you cannot create it with `new Contact();` An activity MUST be created by the Android framework and and initialized in the `onCreate(...)` You must learn about Activity lifecycle in Android : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your response! I would really like to get this as just a class so I can call it from another class like I did, but ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver(); requires that it extends Application or extends Activity. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @user3661750 Don't extend `Activity`. Just pass in a `Context` instance to the `fetchContacts()` method. For example, if calling from an `Activity` or a `Service`, both of them are subclasses of `Context`.